# With CDK, how do I synthesize stack via sdk OR how do I get the template in code?

Tags: aws-cdk

Instead of having to run `cdk synthesize/deploy` manually, I want to build a lambda that uses CDK to synthesize resources for a different service that has dynamic resource needs when the lambda is run. (I will use a different stack to manage the lambda resource). How can I have CDK deploy my stack via code OR how can I use CDK to generate a template that I can synthesize using the CloudFormation SDK?

Getting the template seems like it may be possible using CloudFormationStackArtifact's getTemplate() method, but this is marked as experimental, and I haven't found any examples of this being done. I'm hoping there is a more straightforward way that I just haven't stumbled upon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stack can be accessed as a string from CDK as follows:

`app.synth().getStack(STACK_NAME).template` (Python)

Comment: In Python it would be `app.synth().get_stack(STACK_NAME).template`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -o flag to output the cloudformation result from cdk synth